# Android: ViewHolder pattern and different types of rows?

Tags: android, listview, performance, reusability, listadapter

ViewHolder pattern improves ListView scrolling framerate, as seen in following example:
https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Is it possible to keep this pattern while using different kind of Views for different rows?

In other words, is it possible to do something like:

```
 public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {  
     // calculate viewID here
     if (view == null || *view is not null but was created from different XML than viewID* ) { 
         view = mInflater.inflate(viewId, null);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, though it is far better to override `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` in your Adapter. That will teach Android's object pool to only hand you a row of the proper type back in `getView()`.

Comment: meanwhile, I added needed information as a flag to ViewHolder, it works