# Slow listview scrolling problem

Tags: android, performance, listview, scroll

Got a little ListView problem here. I've got a ListView that goes like

TextView
ImageView
TextView
ImageView
TextView
...

and so on. It has 1000+ items in it, resulting in scrolling being really slow. I tried to improve the performance as advised [here](http://androidanswer.com/questions/4/how-to-increase-performance-of-android-listview-scrolling-is-very-slow) and the overall scrolling performance really improved A LOT.

However, another problem appeared - after a certain amount of scrolling (usually almost right away), the views start "clustering", what used to be ImageView-TextView-ImageView turns to ImageView-ImageView-TextView and so on.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

(P. S. A wild guess - I needed to make the ListView circular (Imagine it as a wheel-of-fortune-like list) and thus overrode the getCount to return hardcoded values and getItem to return position % number of items. Could that have anything to do with it?)

Comment: override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` in your adapter

Comment: read this question and answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081565/android-viewholder-pattern-and-different-types-of-rows

Comment: If you post the code for your adapter then we have a much better chance of helping you figure it out.

Comment: I have to question the usability of a listview with over 1000+ items in it. Would a different approach not be more beneficial? The amount of scrolling users would have to do to reach the bottom would be massive...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UCBMjGV1 Here is my Adapter class, feel free to read, comment and criticise, Im open to suggestions here :)

Comment: you compares a lot of Strings there, don't user if...if, try to user if...elseif.

Comment: Yup, agreed on that one, will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the images have a logical connection to the texts a possible approach would be to aggregate each pair into one element and change the adapter accordingly.

Comment: you stolen my next comment :) +1